How do I access a website from a dynamic URL that depends on a cell value from Excel VBA?
I am trying to get the closing price of a stock from yahoo finance using VBA. I am able to do so by specifying the URL and the class name to get my item, but it somehow returns a "424" error (missing object) when I try to make the url depend on a cell value. Basically I want to be able to acccess the right page depending on the ticker written in a cell.
This is the working code, which goes and takes the closing price and returns it into a cell:
Sub ExtractDataFromWebsite_BANB()
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim htmlDocument As Object
    Dim htmlElement As Object
    Dim extractedData As String
    
    ' Create a new XMLHTTP request object
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Specify the URL of the website you want to scrape
    Dim websiteURL As String
    websiteURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BANB.SW?"
    MsgBox websiteURL
    ' Send a request to the website
    httpRequest.Open "GET", websiteURL, False
    httpRequest.send
    
    ' Create an HTML document object and load the response text into it
    Set htmlDocument = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    htmlDocument.body.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText
    
    ' Extract the desired data
    ' This example assumes you are looking for the first instance of an element with a specific class name
    Set htmlElement = htmlDocument.getElementsByClassName("Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)")(0)
    If Not htmlElement Is Nothing Then
        extractedData = htmlElement.innerText
        ' Output the extracted data to the Immediate Window (Debug.Print) and a message box
        Range("I1").Value = extractedData
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found."
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set httpRequest = Nothing
    Set htmlDocument = Nothing
    Set htmlElement = Nothing
End Sub


Now, I simply changed it a bit to try and get the url that could be dynamically changed according to the value of a cell:
Sub ExtractDataFromWebsite_BANB()
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim htmlDocument As Object
    Dim htmlElement As Object
    Dim extractedData As String
    
    ' Create a new XMLHTTP request object
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Specify the URL of the website you want to scrape
    Dim websiteURL As String
    websiteURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Range("Q1").Value & "/"
    MsgBox websiteURL
    ' Send a request to the website
    httpRequest.Open "GET", websiteURL, False
    httpRequest.send
    
    ' Create an HTML document object and load the response text into it
    Set htmlDocument = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    htmlDocument.body.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText
    
    ' Extract the desired data
    ' This example assumes you are looking for the first instance of an element with a specific class name
    Set htmlElement = htmlDocument.getElementsByClassName("Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)")(0)
    If Not htmlElement Is Nothing Then
        extractedData = htmlElement.innerText
        ' Output the extracted data to the Immediate Window (Debug.Print) and a message box
        Range("I1").Value = extractedData
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found."
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set httpRequest = Nothing
    Set htmlDocument = Nothing
    Set htmlElement = Nothing
End Sub


I have tried playing around with .Text instead of .Value, or + instead of &, with no success. The  URL seems to be a valid string when I debug. What am I doing wrong?

Your code as posted works perfectly OK here. Have you compared the two generated text strings websiteURL ? You will get that error if there is no company with the ticcker symbol you enter into Q1

@RonRosenfeld Yes what is weird is that the two strings seem to be identical, as the inserted MsgBox websiteURL returns the same string. If I delete the ticker symbol, the generated url then sends to a homepage and the error is the same. The error (missing object) seems to imlply that the element with that class name is not existent, which is true for the home page but I can't understand why it is true for the generated url page :(

What exactly is in Q1 when it fails i.e. .../BANB.SW? doesn't have a trailing slash /. Also, you might want to specify the worksheet (qualify the range) e.g. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q1").Value.

SOLVED! Thank you @RonRosenfeld, The cell type of the ticker has to manually be set as "text" instead of "general", this seems to fix it.

@HAL9000 On my system it was set to general. What happens if you leave it as general but access the .Value2 property? What is the ticker symbol you are using?

The cell type of the ticker (in this case Q1) has to manually be set as "text" instead of "general", this seems to fix it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
